# EOT in PHP only displaying one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `products` and when I try to display all products in the table, it only shows one entry. What is wrong with my code?

When I try to `echo $obj->product_id` inside the while loop, it works fine and returns all row.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Products List Start -->
<?php
$results = $connection->query("SELECT product_id, product_name, product_desc, product_buyp, product_quantity FROM products ORDER BY product_id ASC");
if($results){ 
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item = <<<EOT
    <form method="post" action="cartUpdate.php">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product ID</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Instock</th>
                <th>Buy Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{$obj->product_id}</td>
                <td>{$obj->product_name}</td>
                <td>{$obj->product_desc}</td>
                <td>{$obj->product_quantity}</td>
                <td>{$obj->product_buyp}</td>
                <td><input type="number" size="2" maxlength="6" name="product_qty"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{$obj->product_id}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
    <button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button>
    </form>
EOT;
}
echo $products_item;
}
?>    
<!-- Products List End -->
```

Here's my data schema
[image]

Anyway, when I try to add a concat symbol to the `.=<<<EOT` it returns all rows but it also creates a new table.

Comment: Enable error reporting when debugging code please.

Comment: @PeeHaa there is no error. The problem is it only returns one row

Comment: try once while($obj >= $results->fetch_object())

Comment: @DeepKakkar It returns two errors: `Notice: Undefined variable: obj in C:\xampp\htdocs\fonti\admin\purchaseOrder\supplierChoose.php on line 182`

`Notice: Undefined variable: products_item in C:\xampp\htdocs\fonti\admin\purchaseOrder\supplierChoose.php on line 214`

Comment: `$products_item .= <<<EOT` ___Note `.=`___ otherwise you are overwriting `$products_item` each time round the loop

Comment: declare $products_item = ' ' ; before the loop once

Comment: @DeepKakkar still left with `Undefined variable: obj`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it works. but it gives me a seperate `<table>` for each of the product

Comment: Thats because you are outputting a WHOLE table each time round the loop

Comment: ohh you are not concatenating that ... @RiggsFolly good catch

Comment: Why thankyou @DeepKakkar :) Nice handle by the way.

Comment: Looking closer, I would ditch the `heredoc` mechanism completely if I were you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly would you mind giving revising my code for a bit? thank you.

Comment: Too big a job _squire_ that one is down to you!

Comment: @RiggsFolly nvm. I got it. Thanks!

Comment: In your loop now it only displays a single row . To display all you should concatenate .

Answer (score 0):

TRY This 
just added concatenation to $products_item

```
<!-- Products List Start -->
<?php
$results = $connection->query("SELECT product_id, product_name,       product_desc, product_buyp, product_quantity FROM products ORDER BY     product_id ASC");
if($results){ 
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item.= <<<EOT //added conc
   ....
   ....
```

Comment: Please dont start your SO carear as a ___vampire___

Comment: Yes we know it works, when I suggested this in my comment some 10 minutes before you answered, the OP replied in another comment that it worked.